# Is it possible to fake link description of browser tooltip in the foot of a page without using JavaScript?

Tags: web-browser, html

When we point a mouse pointer to a link then in the bottom of a page in a browser we see an URI of that link.

So the question is: is there any way to substitute this link information in a browser description of that link while original *href* address stay unmodified?

**UPDATE**

There is a similar question [How can Google search change the location in a URL tooltip?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126400/how-can-google-search-change-the-location-in-a-url-tooltip) in which explains how to show one href address and while clicking replace the address by another one, but my question is about solving the same problem but from the other side: how to substitute link description or how to modify original href in such way that the link description will be partly shown, for example:

```
<a href="coolsite.com">Coosite.com</a>
```

in this case browser will show "coolsite.com" and link will point to that site.

```
<a href="cooliste.com       some magic symbols:badsite.com">Coolsite.com</a>
```

but in this case browser will show "coolsite.com" however it will point to "badsite.com", is it possible? In other words can it be achieved by modifying `a` html tag without using JS event handlers as it made at Google question above?

**UPDATE 2**

Is it possible to fake link description of browser tooltip in the foot of a page **without using JavaScript at all**? Such situation may happen when user cannot use JavaScript while posting message on a site. So in this case he has only one method to achieve this goal, the method is try to modify href in some tricky way *before* message would be added to the site if this way exists in principle.

Comment: Sort of? I mean you can set a redirect, or use a url shortener.

Comment: @Arminius, no, in that question about Google it says that JS just rewrite href value of link, my question is: Is it possible to substitute a link **description** not a href value.

Comment: But the "description" is taken from the current href value. You can't set text in the status bar independently.

Comment: This used to be possible, but has been either disabled or removed from browsers years ago. See [window.status](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp) JavaScript property on W3Schools website for more information.

Comment: @edem It is a close duplicate of the Google method. You can dynamically change all aspects/attributes of a DOM element with JavaScript. HREF, description, style, etc. And you can do it on click, hover, unclick, etc. If this is not what you are looking for then I am unsure what you are asking.

Comment: @BaconBrad the question is about situations when user cannot modify html tags by JS in principle.